Is it possible to reduce the field size without disrupting generation of public keys?
I have a curious question, i am aware of the curve parameters of secp256k1. i was wondering if its possible to reduce to field to a 130 bit or lower without disrupting the actual functionality.. what i mean by this is the actual generation of secp256k1 public keys should not be disrupted.


i was wondering if its possible to reduce to field to a 130 bit or lower

No, that would be woefully insecure. The security of elliptic curve cryptography scales with the half of the field size. A 133-bit curve would only have 66.5-bit security. That means that with ~266.5 curve operations one can compute the private key for a given public key. This is tiny amount of work for a competent attacker.

without disrupting the actual functionality

Even if it weren't a terrible idea, this would be an extremely invasive change, requiring the entire ecosystem to adopt and switch to a different, smaller, curve. All Bitcoin software would need to adapt.
As far as I know, there aren't even any recommended standardized curves with a size below 160 bits.

what i mean by this is the actual generation of secp256k1 public keys should not be disrupted.

If this were possible, the Bitcoin ecosystem would already have embraced it. secp256k1 uses a specific finite field, the integers modulo 2256 - 232 - 977. If you use a different field, it's a different curve, with different private/public keys and everything.

"there aren't even any elliptic curves standardized with a size below 192 bits" what about secp160k1?

@VojtěchStrnad Huh, fixed! I had checked https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf and didn't see anything below 192 (I guess secp160k1 got removed?).

Yes, it's from SEC 2 Version 1 (https://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf) which goes as low as 112 bits with secp112r1 and secp112r2. Yikes.
